# Google Cloud Endpoint: how to show example response, yaml configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using the swagger YAML that has `examples` block to have request and responses example structure. Something similar to https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/#request-response-bodies. My issue is that the spec works fine in the local swagger UI doc but when this YAML is deployed in the gcloud endpoint, it does not show that `examples` block.

What I expect is that google cloud endpoint to show me the examples of the response similar to the documentation we have for paypal, stripe and other platforms where they also have space in their documentation that shows the example values of the response of the API.

Comment: Are you using [Endpoint Portal] (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/dev-portal-overview) to show the API?  Another word, is this a Endpoint portal issue?

Comment: @WayneZhang yes it is

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet implemented in Cloud Endpoints.
You can track progress of the works on the [Public Issue Tracker: Cloud Endpoints UI/UX for OpenAPI Example](https://issuetracker.google.com/139727175)

If you click button: me too, you will be notified about the tracker changes.